# Create a proposition using three variables

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

We have the variables $p, q, r$.

Create a proposition $φ(p, q, r)→x$, using all three variables, that gives the result $x$.

$x$ should be equal to $p$ if $q = 1$, and equal to $r$ if $q = 0$.

I have created $(p∧q)$ and $(r∧¬q)$.

Is this answer correct? $$φ(p, q, r) ≡ (p→(p∧q)⊻r→(r∧¬q))$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly since $\varphi(1,1,0)$ evaluates to $0$ instead of evaluating to $1$ as you desired. You can use the following method to find the expression you are looking for:

1. Build the truth table you want: $$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline p & q & r & \varphi(p,q,r) \\\hline
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
   1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\\hline
   1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\\hline
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\hline
   0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\\hline
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\\hline
   0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\\hline
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\hline
   \end{array}$$
2. Look for where $\varphi(p,q,r)$ evaluates to $1$; this happens at $\varphi(1,1,1)$, $\varphi(1,1,0)$, $\varphi(1,0,1)$, and $\varphi(0,0,1)$.
3. Write $\varphi(1,1,1)$ as $pqr$, $\varphi(1,1,0)$ as $pq\bar{r}$, $\varphi(1,0,1)$ as $p\bar{q}r$, and $\varphi(0,0,1)$ as $\bar{p}\bar{q}r$.
4. Take the sum of these products: $pqr$ + $pq\bar{r}$ + $p\bar{q}r$ + $\bar{p}\bar{q}r$.
5. Rewrite + as $\lor$, concatenation as $\land$, and the overhead bar as $\lnot$.

The resulting expression is $(p \land q \land r) \lor (p \land q \land \lnot r) \lor  (p \land \lnot q \land r) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q \land r)$. You can use identities to simplify this in any way you want.

Comment: Thank you, that was very clear. How would the expression change if q always started as equal to 0, using only two logical operators? My guess is $φ ≡ p∧(q∨r)$

Comment: Could you say a little more about what you mean by "if $q$ always started as equal to $0$"? If $\varphi(p,q,r) \equiv p \land (q \lor r)$, then $\varphi(0,0,1)$ evaluates to $0$, which doesn't seem like what you want.

Comment: Supposedly, q is always 0 but you're given the option to change it to 1 whenever you want to alter the result. What I think this means, is that q is made redundant but stays in the proposition. Then we're asked to recreate the proposition, using only two logical operators.

Comment: It could be $q→(p∧r)$, if I'm not mistaken it should make sense in this context.

Comment: I don't think $\varphi(p,q,r) \equiv q \implies (p \land r)$ will do the trick because $\varphi(0,0,0)$ evaluates to $1$, which doesn't seem like what you wanted. In the case where $q$ is always $0$, $x$ takes the value that $r$ takes. So this would just be (using the method in my answer) $(p \land \lnot q \land r) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q \land r)$ which is equivalent to and thus can be reduced to $\lnot q \land r$ which uses only 2 connectives, although $p$ isn't a part of this expression.

Comment: I think this what's being requested, thanks for your time!

Comment: @Nika. Nice answer!